# Illustrator art brush corner problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I created a brush because I needed the terminals of my line had angles. But the brush is generating some kind of thorn in the corners, when the brush option "Do not adjust corners and folds" is active.

Any tips to resolve this?

[image: My artwork with brush problems]

Comment: I'm not sure this will work but - did you try simply changing the corner options in the stroke window?

Comment: I tried, but since it's a art brush, the stroke options seems to work.